# Proper way to reimplement openssl_random_pseudo_bytes function in Java

Tags: java, php, openssl, cryptography

I need re-implement behaviour of PHP function `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`, which is according to its [description](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php):

> openssl_random_pseudo_bytes — Generate a pseudo-random string of bytes

As it is just *pseudo-random* string of bytes, and as I need hex representation of it, I could use just [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14623245/1479414). But there is also additional parameter:

> **crypto_strong**
>
> If passed into the function, this will hold a boolean
>   value that determines if the algorithm used was "cryptographically
>   strong", e.g., safe for usage with GPG, passwords, etc. TRUE if it
>   did, otherwise FALSE

So core of my question is: what exactly does this crypto_strong parameter? How I should correctly re-implement this behaviour?

**NB!** Can I just use `java.security.SecureRandom()` class for this purposes?

Comment: Do you need repeatedly the same data given a specific seed (i.e. a key stream), or do you require random numbers?

Comment: Well, in original `php` code this function is used like: `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(XX, true)`.

Comment: That is not correct @Andremoniy. The `$crypto_strong` variable is an output variable indicated if a "cryptographically strong" algorithm was used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function [`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length, &$crypto_strong)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php) indicates in the second parameter *receives* an indication if the generated bytes are cryptographically strong.

This code seems to be used as:

```
openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(XX, true)
```

which doesn't make sense, as it is seemingly treated as an *input parameter* rather than the *output parameter* that it is.

On (embedded) devices without good entropy source to seed the RNG, it may be that the `crypto_strong` parameter is set to false by the function. Obviously it is impossible to set `true` to `false` so this will fail; i.e. *it's a bug in the PHP code* (apparently not caught by the rather permissive type system of PHP itself).

---

The programmer of PHP probably tried to indicate that cryptographically strong PRNG is required. So `new SecureRandom()` seems indeed the best way to go.